# Where is the .log file for an RCP application running from inside eclipse?

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-rcp, stack-trace

During development of an RCP application (running from inside eclipse) I came across a Widget Disposed error for a table part, the stack trace was quickly swamped by debug output on the console and I cannot re-produce the error so I've been trying to find the .log file for the application, where would this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your launch config to find the workspace of your launched RCP (see picture). In this folder there is a `.metadata/.log` file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse logs normal applications at

```
<Your Workspace>/.metadata/.log
<Your Workspace>/.metadata/.bak_n.log
```

RCP application logs go at

```
<Your Workspace>/../runtime-<LaunchConfigurationName>/.metadata/.log
```

You can check your launch configuration names at

```
Run As > Run Configurations
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have ended up in there.